# Can you train a neural network with sentences instead of words for speech to text?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

To start of, I am trying to create a neural network that can change speech audio files into transcribed text. I tried to use Google's API as well as IBM watson's but the quality of transcribing was very bad because of the nature of the words used in the audio files (highly technical, coming from the medical field). So the audio contains several medical terms that Google's and IBM's models just couldn't handle and the quality was very bad.

I have around 30,000 audio files (which are of very good quality) averaging 1 minute per audio file which were **manually** transcribed by someone. I am wondering if I can use the mapping between the audio files and the transcribed text to train a model to recognize the text?

I am aware that most training methods for speech to text have a 1-to-1 mapping between audio files and text. For example, audio file for someone saying a word mapped to that word. However, is it possible to achieve good results with a many to many mapping in this example?

Comment: Why can't you split the audio flies into words? It seems like the best solution because then you can use standard toknization and lemmtation methods etc. The problem with using sentences is mainly that every sentence will represent a value in your dictionary. So many sentences which mean the same but use different word order will have to be saved and your dictionary will be infinite size. Using words is much more compact and I assume you should be able to train a network on your data.

Comment: You would get better luck with this question on stats.stackexchange.com. It is more about ML know-how rather than straight up programming.